# Xml response retrieving issue

Tags: android, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am new to android development and eclipse Juno version.I have been trying with xml parsing. While debugging the execute line to retrieve the xml, it ends up with the following error.

```
// defaultHttpClient
DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
//Below Line Shows the Source not found error.
HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
```

Error:

```
Class File Editor
Source not found
The source attachment does not contain the source for the file DefaultRequestDirector.class.

You can change the source attachment by clicking Change Attached source below:

Change Attached Source...

The source attachment does not contain the source for the file DefaultRequestDirector.class.
```

But I could see the DefaultRequestDirector.class in the package Android 4.1==>org.apache.http.impl.client.
Tried with the Cmd+Shift+O key combination,and also tried the "Clean" option in eclipse, but ends up with the same problem.

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

Try the following code...See if it helps:

```
HttpClient httpclient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpConnectionParams.setConnectionTimeout(httpclient.getParams(), 10000);
HttpPost httppost = new HttpPost(url);
HttpResponse response = httpclient.execute(httppost);
```

Comment: Can u provide your complete code..I want to see what have you imported..??